# Choosing when to insert data into Identity column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to do a bulk insert from a select statement, but sometimes I would like to save the Identity from Table2 to Table1, but sometimes I want the Identity in the Table to be generated automatically when there is no data in Table2, So how would this be accomplished?

```
 INSERT INTO Table (ID,Name) 
 SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN Col1 ELSE @@identity END ID,
  Col2 Name,
 FROM Table2
```

Is this possible or do I have to do 2 seperate bulk import processes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need two bulk inserts:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table ON

INSERT INTO Table (ID,Name) 
SELECT 
Col1
Col2 Name
FROM Table2
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table OFF

INSERT INTO Table (Name) 
SELECT 
Col2 Name
FROM Table2
WHERE Col1 IS NULL
```